# Integrated Help - Merged Help Indexes

Tags: productivity, chm

If anyone has had more than a couple of Microsoft tools or products installed (or a local install of the MSDN library) side by side, you might have noticed that opening help (hitting F1) or opening, say, SQL Server Books Online causes the help indexes to be re-indexed - this is usually after installing a new product or tool.

This can be a really, really time consuming exercise!

Does anyone know a way to prevent or opt out of having combined help indexes?
At best, even just preventing the reindexing at all?

Answer (score 1):

Installers should ask if you need it (Developer Express installer does this), but really, don't even bother installing integrated help. Use the web, you can google the page faster than the library will load.